# In statement with parameters in Crystal Report Command object

Tags: sql, parameters, crystal-reports, command

I am trying to modify the code of an exsisting SQL report.  This report uses a command object.  Currently the SQl codes says the following:

```
 WHERE **dept.definition_id ={?Measure}**
     AND (({?Period Interval}=2
             AND dept_qd_later.sum_facts_id IS NULL
             AND dept_qd.DENOMINATOR_QUARTER IS NOT NULL)
     OR ({?Period Interval}=3
             AND dept_md_later.sum_facts_id IS NULL 
             AND dept_md.DENOMINATOR_MONTH IS NOT NULL))

 LAST
```

I would like to modify the "Measure Parameter" to accept multiple values.  I have updated the command parameter box to accept multiple values.  I have tried to modify the SQL to the below in statement:

```
 WHERE **dept.definition_id in({?Measure})**
     AND (({?Period Interval}=2
             AND dept_qd_later.sum_facts_id IS NULL
             AND dept_qd.DENOMINATOR_QUARTER IS NOT NULL)
     OR ({?Period Interval}=3
             AND dept_md_later.sum_facts_id IS NULL
             AND dept_md.DENOMINATOR_MONTH IS NOT NULL))) 
 LAST
```

However, when I try to insert multiple measure IDs, the report does not run.  Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?  I am a Crystal novice so please respond in plain language. Thanks!

Comment: Report doesnot run.... what is the error

Comment: What datatype does the `measure` parameter have? is it string?. Are you sending the values comma delimited?.

Answer (score 0):

I think David is right. I tried something similar with a command object and it works when entering a comma separated list into the parameter prompt. Which means that you don't need to set the "allow multiple values" option on the parameter.
If the field were a string, you would have to enter the values with quotes as if they were part of the SQL statement.